# Making a text input conditional on the selection of a specific list item

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm brand new at `VueJs` and `JS` in general, so perhaps my answer is obvious, but I have a page where I would like a text input box to only appear when user selects the document type 'Write Individual'. However, I'm not sure I'm writing this syntactically accurate as it's not providing me with expected behavior. I'd appreciate tips as to what is the best way forward!

Vue

```
    <template v-if="attachmentAccepted">
  <b-field
    :label="t('document_type')"
  >
    <b-select
      v-model="documentType"
      icon="file-alt"
      :disabled="waiting.updateAttachment"
    >
      <optgroup
        v-for="group in allDocumentTypeGroups"
        :key="group.id"
        :label="t(group.name)"
      >
        <option
          v-for="type in group.documentTypes"
          :key="type.id"
          :value="type.id"
        >
          {{(type.name)}}
        </option>
      </optgroup>
    </b-select>

  </b-field>
```

and this is where I've really been struggling, the document types appear to be received in a JSON, so my next step would be the view the parsed data so I can accurately reference it in my v-if statement, but being new at Vue I have zero clue as to how to view the parsed data. `console.log(this.documentTypes)` hasn't worked.

```
.then(({data}) => {
        this.participants = data.participants;
        this.installmentData = data.installments;
        this.installmentData = data.installments;
        this.installmentData.paymentDateStart = moment(data.installments.paymentDateStart).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        this.installmentData.paymentDateEnd = moment(data.installments.paymentDateEnd).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        this.documentTypes = JSON.parse(data.documentTypes);
        this.formattedDocumentTypes = JSON.parse(data.formattedDocumentTypes);
        this.loading = false;
      })
```

edit: props + data

```
export default {
  name: 'AttachmentEditForm',
  mixins: [AttachmentTypeMixin],
  components: { DocumentCheckbox },
  props: {
    attachment: Object,
    slideIndex: Number,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      waiting: {},
    }
  },
```

Comment: What props/data do you have defined in your component?

Comment: @bassxzero added an edit with those! :)

Comment: You are referencing things like `this.documentTypes`, but you don't have them defined in your `data()` object or props. Try defining them in your `data()` before you try to assign them values like this `this.documentTypes = JSON.parse(data.documentTypes)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to first define your data in data function :

```
    data() {
    return {
      waiting: {},
      participants: null,
      installmentData: {
        paymentDateStart: null,
        paymentDateEnd: null,
      },
      documentTypes: null,
      formattedDocumentTypes: null,
      loading: false
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

First, to console your documentTypes, why not to do console.log(data.documentTypes) in .then()?
Second. regarding the conditional showing the text field. You are absolutely right about using v-if, you just need to decide which **documentType** value is supposed to make the field visible and check it. In turn, this documentType is set by selecting an item in the list, and it should be in your data{} section, btw (I couldn't find it there). So, something like this:

```
<template v-if="attachmentAccepted">
  <b-field
    v-if="documentType == 'some_value_to_make_this_true'"
    :label="t('document_type')"
  >
    <b-select
      v-model="documentType"
      icon="file-alt"
      :disabled="waiting.updateAttachment"
    >
      <optgroup
        v-for="group in allDocumentTypeGroups"
...

export default {
  name: 'AttachmentEditForm',
  mixins: [AttachmentTypeMixin],
  components: { DocumentCheckbox },
  props: {
    attachment: Object,
    slideIndex: Number,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      documentType: null,
      waiting: {},
    }
  },
```